# Parse text block into database fields using python

Tags: python, sql, parsing

I have the following block of text being stored in a single LONGTEXT database field and need to parse it out into another table using a python script. Each block has a variable number of lines and there is unnecessary text at the top and bottom that can be deleted by subtracting the BEGIN field from the END field. Additionally, 'name' needs to be replaced with the ID from another table before being inserted. As a novice at python what is the easiest way to do this? Thanks :-)

BEGIN field

```
show 
x1b[Kadmin@testbox> show counters
Global counters:
Elapsed time since last sampling: 304.308 seconds

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total tests shown: 0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

x1b[2048;1Hx1b[Kx1b[?1lx1b>admin@testbox>
```

END field

```
show 
x1b[Kadmin@testbox> show counters
Global counters:
Elapsed time since last sampling: 304.308 seconds

name                                   value     rate
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
packet_sent                          1234456    29305
packet_received                      1234758    29305
packet_allocated                     1234826    29288
packet_lost                                0        0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total tests shown: 4
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

x1b[2048;1Hx1b[Kx1b[?1lx1b>admin@testbox>
```

Code so far

```
import mysqldb
import difflib
from difflib_data import *

# Connect to database
db = db.connect("10.2.1.39","username","password","TEST_DATA")

def main():
     # Read TEST_RUN_ID
     trid = cursor.execute("""select TEST_RUN_ID from PERFORMANCE2""")
     for row in trid

     # Read START
     start = cursor.execute("""select START from PERFORMANCE2""")
     for row in start

     # Read END
     end = cursor.execute("""select END from PERFORMANCE2""")
     for row in end

     # Detect change between start and end
     d = difflib.Differ()
     modified = d.compare(start_lines, end_lines)

     # Parse into lines?
     for line in modified
        counterstring =
        trid =
        value = parselist[1]
        rate = parselist[2]
        tstamp =
             line 9 position 34,37
             modified.read()

     # Substitute counter id for counter string
     counterid = cursor.execute("""select COUNTER_ID from COUNTER_STRINGS where NAME = %counterstring""")

# Insert into COUNTER_DATA
try:
     cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO COUNTER_DATA VALUES (counterid, trid, value, rate, tstamp)""")
     db.commit()
except:
     db.rollback()

db.close()
```

Comment: Try to rephrase this question around the specific parsing problem - what is the text you have to start with, and what do you want to extract from it? All the database stuff is just a distraction.

Comment: name                                   value     rate
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
packet_sent                          1234456    29305
packet_received                      1234758    29305
packet_allocated                     1234826    29288

Comment: Need to split these lines into separate variables